# Getting ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT in rxjs while running angular project

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular15

While trying to execute `ng serve` in angular 15 project. I am getting the below error,

```
node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4
    setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);
                             ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import 'node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from D:\officeprojects\Feature-TEPL22-10747\Portal-UI\CMS-APIM-New\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
Did you mean to import node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:387:17)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:893:10)
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: If you don't provide a repro I don't see how anyone will be able to help you out on this